# How to store github access_token in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-api

I want to integrate GitHub OAuth to my rails app, I don't want to use the the third party gems, like OmniAuth, warden-github and so on. According to [GitHub Basics of Authentication](https://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/), I got the access_token. The Guide store the access_token to the session:

```
...
session[:access_token] = JSON.parse(result)['access_token']
...
```

but if another user login my app by github account, the value of session[:access_token] will be override, how to handle this situation？Hope someone can give me some good ideas, thanks in advance!

Comment: If another user login they have their own instance of `session`.

Comment: The session token is stored in a cookie, which lives on the user's computer.  This is what enables each user to have their own session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both @dimakura and @Max Williams have pointed out - Rails stores that data in its `session` object in a cookie, which is stored on the client/user's computer. Thus, each user will have his own `session[:access_token]` which you can use to perform calls to the GitHub API for that particular user.

For a more thorough description on how Rails uses the `session` object I highly recommend [this article](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/03/17/how-rails-sessions-work/) by Justin Weiss.